# How many first gen PS3s are affacted by and how can I avoid YLOD?

Tags: ps3

I want to buy a second hand 1st gen PS3. What are the odds that I'll be affected by a YLOD and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Not sure if there is an actual "statistic" on how often they YLOD, but to avoid it just make sure it's in an open, cool space with lots of room to breath.  Not leaving it on for long periods of time as well will help, give it a rest from time to time.

Comment: Hehehe the first time I read this I thought it said "-how can I avoid YOLO?" XD